# How to save video on SD card recorded through android camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard

I am using camera intent for video recording, see my code here

```
    Button makeVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonmakeVideo );
                makeVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);

                    }
                });



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) 
                {

                    uriVideo = data.getData();
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());


                    cameraVideoList.add(timeStamp);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    cameraVideoURIList.add(uriVideo.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

I successfully record video and can play the video in my app but the videos are stored in camera memory, I want to create a directory on SD card like dirMyVideos and store the videos in the directory how is it possible please guide me in this respect.

Here is my logcat
[image]

Comment: posted answer check it let me know if you any doubts..

Comment: Thnx kalyan for your ans, my app crashes as I click stop recording

Comment: post logcat what you are getting....

Comment: Please check my logcat